# Download file corrupt. Content-type not working?

Tags: php, download, content-type

I want to allow a user to download a pdf file, the download code is below....for some odd reason even though the file is being downloaded I get an error saying that the file has been damaged on the server...Could someone help me and point out where I am making my mistake.

```
<php

$name = $_POST["name_first"];

    $mail = $_POST['email'];


    $number = $_POST['phone_number'];

            $email_message = "first name: {$name} email is {$mail} number is {$number} ";
            mail('fanaa@gmail.com', 'Form Response', $email_message);

                if ($mail == "" OR $name == "" OR $number == "")
                    {
                        echo "Enter valid details  ";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tokina.pdf"');
                        readfile('docs/tokina.pdf');

                    }
?>
```

Comment: You can do a binary compare of the original file with the downloaded file to see if you can find out the problem. If the difference is only in the first or last 2 bytes, I might be able to help.

Comment: Have you additional output somewhere in the executed scripts, like whitespaces, `echo`, or something?

Comment: If your pdf file is ok, maybe u can use library email such as http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: @KingCrunch yes this bit of code is actually a part of an if statement....I've edited my question after your query please look into it

Comment: I suspect a <?php ?> tag closure issue. If there is whitespace at the beginning or at the end of your script, outside the <?php ?> tags, they will be output causing data corruption. Or, it could be a content-length issue: have you tried adding a line like the following? header("Content-length: ".filesise("tokina.pdf") );

Comment: @Paolo Stefan...The header change you asked me to make didn't work either. There are no gaps between the PHP enclosures, I checked twice :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used this code to download pdfs:

```
header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Type: application/octetstream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-length: ".filesize($file));
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"");
    readfile("$file");                
  }
```

This should be fine, and make sure there are no spaces or return characters (don't escape php at all is the best solution).

If you find your still having problems, open the corrupted file with notepad (there may be a php error warning inside).

Hope this helps!

Comment: could you please tell me what $file means I did not get that part

Comment: $file is the filepath, ie ../myfiles/thisone/example.pdf, in your case you can put $file = 'docs/tokina.pdf'

Comment: Abe, perhaps it would be clearer if you wrote `readfile($file);` without the quotes.

Comment: "Content-Type: application/octetstream" Header made it on my case. Thanks

Comment: Opening pdf file with notepad in such cases is a good suggestions. Thanks it helped a lot to me

Answer (score 3):

Remove the headers and look at the page, do you see any error messages? If PHP outputs anything else than the actual PDF source, the file will appear to be corrupted.

Comment: If I remove the header for the first line...its gives an output as tokina.pdf.htm

Comment: if I remove both the header's then PHP shows a page with binary encoded lines

Comment: Obvious but i didn't think about this, that helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

enable PHP extension `php_gettext` and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

try taking out the double quotes in

```
header('Content-type: "application/octet-stream"');
```

so it becomes

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: I think content type for PDF should be application/pdf. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I first tried application/pdf. I got the same error, after a bit of research I read about application/octet-stream and integrated it into the code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your content-type is not correct. try this one:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile('original.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PDF file tokina.pdf is either not uploaded or not in the same directory as the PHP file. That's why it's saving as "tokina.pdf.htm" - it's loading the HTML for a 404 page instead. That is why your browser/PDF viewer thinks the file is "corrupted" - because its extension is PDF but its contents are not.

Make sure the file is uploaded, and if it is, make sure `readfile` is pointing to the correct path. If it's not in the same folder, use a relative/absolute path, for example:

```
readfile('docs/tokina.pdf');
```

And yes, the content type should be `application/pdf`

Comment: I am using WAMP server to test my code...and the location of the PDF file is in the 'WWW' directory of WAMP

Answer (score 0):

Using this script

```
   header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filenamepath));

   readfile($filenamepath);
```

I had the same problem. Comparing the original file and the downloaded file with a hexadecimal editor like UltraEdit, I found some characters at the beginning of the corrupted file.

The problem was that after `?>` marking end of PHP code there were line terminators several times in my code.

Remove all the line terminators after `?>` and read also the forum article [Downloaded Files are corrupt - Common Problem](http://www.zubrag.com/forum/index.php?topic=465.0). That worked for me.

I hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
$download_path = your path (where to look for the files)
set_time_limit(0);
$file_url = $download_path . $data['link'];
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file_url). '"');
//then to read the file
readfile($file_url);
```

this usually works for me